# Awk program to validate date format inside the file(YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS.NNNNNN )

Tags: shell, awk

I will receive a file, that will contains name and joined date.
I need to validate the file whether the date is in required format and it is valid or not.

Required date format : `YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS.NNNNNN eg: 2021-01-12-14.03.38.012098`

**Sample content in side file**

```
Name|Joined_date

aaa|2019-01-12-14.03.38.012098

bbb|2020-03-12-12.04.38.012088

ccc|2018-01-12-14.03

ddd|2019-13-33-14.03.38.012078

eee|2017-03-11-11.04.38.012088
```

**`Desired output`**

```
aaa|2019-01-12-14.03.38.012098

bbb|2020-03-12-12.04.38.012088

eee|2017-03-11-11.04.38.012088
```

3rd record doesn't have MM.SS.NNNNNN, so that record need to be ignored....
4th record - MONTH and DATE is not valid, so it needs to be ignored.

**The code I tried, but it didn't work**

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' ' $2 = "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}$" ' filename
```

Could you please help me to achieve the expected output?

Comment: 1. Learn regexes 2. Learn awk scripting 3. Write a regex that will match requested lines 4. Validate dates further by checking valid data ranges of each field.

Comment: Hi Cyrus/Kamil…Thanks for comments...  I'm beginner for this awk program & in learning stage. I'm trying my best get desired output. here is there code which I tried "awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' ' $2 = "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{6}$" ' filename"

Answer (score 0):

The operator `=` checks for literal string equivalence. To check against a regular expression, use the operator `~`:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$2 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}$/' filename
```

Notice also the backslashes to match literal dots.

It is possible to have a regex in a `"string"` (and necessary if you construct the regex by concatenating strings and variables) but for a static regex, we normally use slashes as delimiters.

I would not extend the regex to check for valid month numbers and days in months, though of course it's possible. Instead, I would split into individual numbers and check that they make sense. (With GNU Awk you could even pass the numbers to `mktime` to check for a valid date.)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```sh
gawk -F '|' '
    BEGIN {
        regex = "^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).[0-9]+$"
    }
    function valid_date(datetime,      m, datespec) {
        if (match(datetime, regex, m)) {
            datespec = m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3] " " m[4] " " m[5] " " m[6]
            return (mktime(datespec) != -1)
        }
        return 0
    }
    valid_date($2)
' file
```

Now, this will happily accept `2020-01-32` to mean `Feb 1, 2020`. If you want to strictly check that the input date appears on the calendar and clock, there's more work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
match($2,/^([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){3}(\.[0-9]{2}){2})\.[0-9]{6}$/,a) {
    dt = gensub(/[.-]/," ","g",a[1])
    secs = mktime(dt)
    if ( dt == strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S",secs) ) {
        print
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaa|2019-01-12-14.03.38.012098
bbb|2020-03-12-12.04.38.012088
eee|2017-03-11-11.04.38.012088
```